# How Can I find values not existing in other column in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

So - what i've mentioned - I want to find unique values from left column when compared to the right column.

I only want to have values, which are not occuring in other column. [like here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyl07.png)
I know about existing
`flatten()` formula, but it shows unique values compared to these from left.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=filter(A2:A,isna(xmatch(A2:A,B2:B)),len(A2:A))
```